# How to solve an error: unable to find valid certification path to requested target error in Java?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, pkix

I have a problem with java mail. I configured my code like this:

```
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSenderImpl.setHost(env.getProperty("smtp.host"));
    mailSenderImpl.setPort(env.getProperty("smtp.port", Integer.class));
    mailSenderImpl.setProtocol(env.getProperty("smtp.protocol"));
    mailSenderImpl.setUsername(env.getProperty("smtp.username"));
    mailSenderImpl.setPassword(env.getProperty("smtp.password"));

    Properties javaMailProps = new Properties();
    javaMailProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    javaMailProps.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
```

And this are the properties:

```
    smtp.host= email.server.com

    smtp.port=587

    smtp.protocol=smtp

    smtp.username=email@server.com

    smtp.password=mypassword
```

Then I run the code. I got this exception:

```
    org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
    nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
    nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; message exceptions (1) are:
    Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
    nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
    nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
    nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; message exception details (1) are:
    Failed message 1:
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
    nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1918)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:652)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:397)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:308)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:297)
    at com.sivalabs.springapp.UserServiceTest.testMail(UserServiceTest.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:548)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:485)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1913)
    ... 37 more
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 47 more
    Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 53 more
```

I read titles like this, I understand that java needs ca certificate then I install it by keytool.... for my environmental %JAVA_HOME% path and also for my jdk.1.7.0 path but I'm still getting the same error. So where do i still make a mistake?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It is possible that between the CA and the certificate you get, there are one or more intermediaries. These must exist in your keystore or they must be passed along in the handshake.

Answer (score 2):

You have to export certificate from your SMTP server and import into Java key store.

Import the Certificate as a Trusted Certificate: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html

Answer (score 0):

This happens also if you have a PKI configured (via system property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` for example) using Mutual-Authentication and the MTA do not provide a client-cert.

Try to add the MTAs cert to the truststore.