# while sending email getting following error - java 6 tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response; nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
  unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the code that causes the Exception.

Comment: The first Google result for `SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target` has your answer. Please do some more research into Tomcat and its HTTPS configuration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in JavaMail : PKIX path building failed unable to find valid certification path to requested target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122099/error-in-javamail-pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification)

Comment: The remote server isn't trusted by your local server. Verify the remote server's certificate, and then make arrangements for your server to trust the remote one.

Answer (score 1):

**javax.mail.MessagingException** can occur due to many reasons. Since you have not posted any code , it is virtually impossible to say correctly what caused this.

**looking at second part of error** "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Now again i cannot say with 100% certainty but most probable these kind of error are related to  certificate . ie most probably Your Java runtime doesn’t trust the certificate.

Normally Java verifies certificates through the standard chain of trust mechanism. But if that chain terminates with a certificate that Java doesn’t trust, then Java will complain in the way described above.

```
The solution if this is the case would be to 

1. Download the certificate from the remote SMTP server

2. Import the certificate into your local truststore
```

Detailed information for these are available at below link

http://springinpractice.com/2012/04/29/fixing-pkix-path-building-issues-when-using-javamail-and-smtp

Also check the following links

[Error in JavaMail : PKIX path building failed unable to find valid certification path to requested target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122099/error-in-javamail-pkix-path-building-failed-unable-to-find-valid-certification)

[how to ignore server cert error in javamail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894954/how-to-ignore-server-cert-error-in-javamail)

[How to solve an error: unable to find valid certification path to requested target error in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719825/how-to-solve-an-error-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-targ)